# Macro arguments HEX and DEC

Tags: c++, arduino, macros

According to that guide: [enter link description here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=46900.0)

i wrote:

```
#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
 #define DEBUG_PRINT(x)  Serial.print (x)
 #define DEBUG_PRINTLN(x)  Serial.println (x)
 #define DEBUG_PRINT_HEX(x)  Serial.print (x, HEX)
 #define DEBUG_PRINT_DEC(x)  Serial.print (x, DEC)
#else
 #define DEBUG_PRINT(x)
 #define DEBUG_PRINTLN(x)
 #define DEBUG_PRINT_HEX(x)
 #define DEBUG_PRINT_DEC(x)
#endif
```

if i call a function:

```
uint32_t versiondata;
DEBUG_PRINT_HEX((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX);
DEBUG_PRINT_DEC((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC);
uint8_t uidLength;
DEBUG_PRINT_DEC(uidLength, DEC);
```

the compiler give me:

`error: macro "DEBUG_PRINT_DEC" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1`
`error: macro "DEBUG_PRINT_HEX" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1`

Someone can explain me why does not works?

Comment: remove the second parameter. you have DEC or HEX in macro name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error message. You had defined this macro:

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT_HEX(x)
```

This macro want one argument: the `x`

And you call the macro with two arguments:

```
DEBUG_PRINT_HEX((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX);
```

1 argument: `(versiondata>>24) & 0xFF`

2 argument: `HEX`

Just call the macro like this:

```
DEBUG_PRINT_HEX((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF);
```